# Approximately how much does a catcher's gear weigh?

Tags: baseball, equipment, mlb

About how much does all the gear that a (professional) baseball catcher wears weigh? I know some are made of light-weight material but I'd still like to know about how much it all weighs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eh, about 5 pounds. Maybe 10 if you have a heavy set of shinguards and one of the hockey-style masks. You could just look it up on some sporting good websites. Should have specs for all the gear (mask & helmet, chest protector, and shin guards).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. However, please note that we [strongly prefer answers which don't need readers to go elsewhere to find the actual answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) - could you add the information as to what counts as a typical set of catcher's gear to this answer?

Comment: "Go find out for yourself elsewhere" is no different from telling them to just google it, and there is nothing to support the core claims made. I could equally say they're typically 47 pounds, maybe 63 if you're wearing the box and ankle guards too, and be just as valid.